# Triggers: Exposing LogicalOp flag

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

If you dig around in ILSpy, etc. you'll find an enum:

```
namespace System.Windows
{
    internal enum LogicalOp
    {
        Equals,
        NotEquals
    }
}
```

If you did around further, you'll see that all the various triggers in thier .Seal() method do something like:

```
base.TriggerConditions[i] = new TriggerCondition(this._conditions[i].Property, **LogicalOp.Equals**, ...
```

Hardcoded! But this would be such a useful flag (and expanding it to do other things like comparisons, etc). I was thinking of ways to implement this... I'm thinking an attached property on TriggerBase and have that "patch" the TriggerConditions with reflection or expression trees... Haven't tried it yet... but its looking like the Seal() method is going to get called later and thus the TriggerConditions aren't going to be created....

Also, if I used the built in:

```
private bool Match(object state, object referenceValue)
{
    if (this.LogicalOp == LogicalOp.Equals)
    {
        return object.Equals(state, referenceValue);
    }
    return !object.Equals(state, referenceValue);
}
```

I'd be limited to Equals and NotEquals.

Sigh... seems like this is 99% implemented, why couldn't they have exposed this the other 1%?